# Bootstrap Dropdown not working with Kartik ExportMenu widget in yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, conflict, yii2

When I use Kartik ExportMenu widget in my code, all dropdown stop working..

Here's a sample of code I am using,

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([ 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'columns' => $gridColumns ]);
```

the widget is affecting only that single page, dropdowns on other pages are working..

After some Googling, I found that its conflicting with bootstrap js file.. which I am including in my Asset `'bootstrap.min.js'`,

if I remove `bootstrap.min.js`, obviously.. all dropdown should stop working.. but the dropdown on the page I have widget are working..

In my project I need to use both of them...

Is there any solution, anyone can think off??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that use unset concept in that particular page.

add following lines at the end of your code.

```
<?php unset($this->assetBundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a showColumnSelector to the widget options and assign value true to it. as in:

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns'=>$gridColumn,'showColumnSelector' => \true,
]);
```